# Triggering Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-integration

I'm still new to Spring Integration and Spring framework as a whole so please bear with me. I've been looking at this example.

https://github.com/benjaminwootton/spring-integration-examples/blob/master/target/classes/direct-channel-example.xml

https://github.com/benjaminwootton/spring-integration-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/examples/components

I'm wondering how do I or Spring trigger the method exactly?
I'm trying to do a round-robin using direct channel for my REST services. My REST services consumes messages and processes it.

I understand that with direct channel, Spring will round-robin through the subscribers but I'm not sure how Spring actually triggers that method.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first class citizen in the Spring Integration is `MessageChannel`, so to allow for message (HTTP request) travel in the Integration flow, we should place message to some `<channel>`.

Since you say that you are in the REST service, I assume you use:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/path1,/path2"
                 request-channel="myChannel"/>
```

Here the `myChannel` is a component to where the HTTP request will be sent after conversion to the Spring Integration `Message`.

Of course, the `MessageChannel` is a `pipe`, when we push a thing into one side and there really should be something on the other side to poll that thing. In case of `DirectChannel` it is some `subscriber`. And we involve here the second class citizen - `MessageHandler`.

And if you use there something like `<service-activator input-channel="myChannel" ref="foo" method="service">`, the call stack may look like:

```
DirectChannel#send -> UnicastingDispatcher#dispatch -> 
          ServiceActivatingHandler#handleMessage -> MethodInvokingMessageProcessor#processMessage -> 
                MessagingMethodInvokerHelper#process -> foo#service
```

HTH